# $ \forall\;n\;<\;3 \;$,$ \exists \;(a;b;c)$ such as $ a^n+b^n=c^n$ and, specifically $4693^{20}+4110^{20}\neq4709^{20}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm working on Fermat property that says that :

$\forall \; n\geq3, \; \nexists \;(a;b;c)$ such as $ a^n+b^n=c^n  $

I am asked to prove that it is necessary to use congruences greater or equal to 7 in order to prove that :

$4693^{20}+4110^{20}\neq4709^{20}$

I checked that for modulo 7, the equality doesn't hold but I don't know how to prove it in the general case.

Thank you

Romain (from France)

Comment: The title is not correct. It is not true that $a^n+b^n=c^n$ for all $n<3$.

Comment: Thank you, did I correct it right ?

Comment: How to prove what in the general case?  I think, but I am not at all sure, that the point is for you to show that congruences mod $2,3,5$ don't suffice.  It's phrased poorly.  Obviously you don't need congruences at all...if you wanted to, you could just write out both sides and check.

Comment: You are right, I need to show that congruences below 7 don't suffice. Do I have to check for 4 and 6 also since two numbers can be equal modulo 2 but not modulo 4 ?

Comment: And I was also wondering if there was a way to directly say that we have to look at modulos above 7 in order to demonstrate the inequality, without having to test with 2,3,4,5,6.

Comment: Yes, you should check $4$ as well.  No need to check $6$ since a solution mod $2$ and mod $3$ would give you a solution mod $6$.  I don't think there's a short cut,  but none of the computations are difficult.

Comment: Should say, your title doesn't make any sense.  More broadly, there is no point referring to Fermat's Last Theorem at all.  You have a particular equation that you need to test, that's it.  In theory you could invoke Fermat to settle it, but that would be preposterous overkill.